# How to build associated records before "tenant" class is saved with acts_as_tenant gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations, acts-as-tenant

Example...

I have a class called `client` which is my `tenant` model.
I have associated records to save along with each new `client` that gets created.
Let's call them `tasks`.
I created an `after_initialize` callback inside of `client` that calls a method called `build_defaults` which does the following...

```
def build_defaults
self.tasks.build(
  Task.new({
    :name => 'task 1',
    :description => 'task 1 desc',
    :view_module => 'task_1_template'
  }),
  Task.new({
    :name => 'task 2',
    :description => 'task 2 desc',
    :view_module => 'task_2_template'
  }),
  Task.new({
    :name => 'task 3',
    :description => 'task 3 desc',
    :view_module => 'task_3_template'
  }),
  Task.new({
    :name => 'task 4',
    :description => 'task 4 desc',
    :view_module => 'task_4_template'
  }),
  Task.new({
    :name => 'task 5',
    :description => 'task 5 desc',
    :view_module => 'task_5_template'
  })
)
end
```

The `task` class is setup as `acts_as_tenant :client`

When I go to do `@client = new Client( :name => "Test Client" )`
It raises `ActsAsTenant::Errors::NoTenantSet: ActsAsTenant::Errors::NoTenantSet`

Is there a way to conditionally bypass acts_as_tenant's check when it's a new_record? or a better way to handle this type of thing?

I'm fairly new to rails / ruby as of a few months ago...?

**UPDATE**

Well, I figured out if I change it to an "after_create" and set `ActsAsTenant.current_tenant = self` within the method I can do `self.tasks.create!` calls... but not sure if overriding ActsAsTenant.current_tenant is a good idea?

```
  after_create :build_defaults
  def build_defaults
    ActsAsTenant.current_tenant = self
    self.tasks.create!({
      :name => 'Facebook > Page Like',
      :description => 'Request that they like your page.',
      :view_module => 'facebook_page_like'
    })
    self.tasks.create!({
      :name => 'Facebook > Share',
      :description => 'Share a link on Facebook',
      :view_module => 'facebook_share_link'
    })
    self.tasks.create!({
      :name => 'Twitter > Tweet',
      :description => 'Post a tweet on a user behalf.',
      :view_module => 'twitter_tweet'
    })
    self.tasks.create!({
      :name => 'Twitter > Follow',
      :description => 'Follow the company twitter user.',
      :view_module => 'twitter_follow'
    })
    self.tasks.create!({
      :name => 'Giveaway Share',
      :description => 'This allows you to earn 5 extra entries by re-sharing this giveaway.',
      :view_module => 'giveaway_share'
    })
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new tenant and then want to create a number of records associated with the new client, you will first need to set the current tenant or acts_as_tenant will not allow you to do so.

Your approach works, but acts_as_tenant has a specific API for this as well (also check the read me):

**Setting the current tenant for a block**

```
ActsAsTenant.with_tenant(newly_created_tenant) do
  # Current tenant is set for all code in this block
end
```

This works.

However, if you want to give the new tenant direct access to his app after creating his account. You would be better of logging him in and then creating the defaults. How to log him in is dependent on your authentication solution.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, this is very helpful and was what I was looking for.
Keep doing what you do!